# Is it possible to save the rxloggerlevel level's?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a launch file launching several nodes and I'm interested on saving a certain configuration of warn/debug/info depending on the node. Is it possible to save a specific configuration or a way of launching it setting the levels accordingly other than changing them manually at every execution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10583/is-it-possible-to-save-the-rxloggerlevel-level%27s?/) by [quimnuss](https://answers.ros.org/users/663/quimnuss/) on ROS Answers with karma: 169 on 2011-07-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. You can set the [ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE) environment variable and have that point to a custom log4cxx config that sets the loggerlevels how you want it.

I guess you want to set debug for your package enabled, then use this entry:

```
log4j.logger.ros.PACKAGE=DEBUG
```

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on 2011-07-14**:
There's a ros-specific example at http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosconsole#Configuration.  Rospy uses a different system based on the Python logging module, described here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview/Logging.  At the bottom of the page it describes how to set up a config file for this.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-07-13**:
Actually, since roscpp is using log4cxx, its documentation on the config file format might be the right one: http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/index.html. Im not sure if this approach works for rospy though since it doesn't use log4cxx.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-13**:
There is an example in my post. To check syntax and specifics about rosconsole, click the link in my post and then also look at rosconsole. It's in rosconsole, so I would guess it is loaded in node init.

**Comment by [quimnuss](https://answers.ros.org/users/663/quimnuss/) on 2011-07-13**:
Looks like it! So I'd have to create a config file and point the ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE to it. Where can I find the syntax or an example of a config file? When is it loaded? when roscore is launched? when rxconsole is launched? (I'm sorry the documentation about the subject is too scarce...)